# Chebyshev in relation to average and expectation

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

I have 2 questions w.r.t average and expectation and how it relates to Chebyshevs inequality. My text book states the following.

In order to illustrate the relative advantage of Chebyshev's inequality compared to Markov's consider the following example. Let $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ be $n$ independent identically distributed Bernoulli random variables and let $\hat{\mu}_{n}=\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$ be their average. We would like to bound the probability that $\hat{\mu}_{n}$ deviates from $\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]$ by more $\operatorname{than} \varepsilon$ (this is the central question in machine learning). We have $\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}\right]=\mu$ and by independence of $X_{i}$-s and Theorem B.26 we have $\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n^{2}} \operatorname{Var}\left[n \hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n^{2}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{Var}\left[X_{i}\right]=$ $\frac{1}{n} \operatorname{Var}\left[X_{1}\right]$. By Markov's inequality
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\hat{\mu}_{n}-\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right] \geq \varepsilon\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\hat{\mu}_{n} \geq \mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]+\varepsilon\right) \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]}{\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]+\varepsilon}=\frac{\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}\right]}{\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}\right]+\varepsilon}
$$
Note that as $n$ grows the inequality stays the same. By Chebyshev's inequality we have
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\hat{\mu}_{n}-\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right] \geq \varepsilon\right) \leq \mathbb{P}\left(\left|\hat{\mu}_{n}-\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]\right| \geq \varepsilon\right) \leq \frac{\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]}{\varepsilon^{2}}=\frac{\operatorname{Var}\left[X_{1}\right]}{n \varepsilon^{2}}
$$

Theorem B.26. If $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$ are independent random variables then
$$
\operatorname{Var}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{Var}\left[X_{i}\right]
$$

What I dont understand is why it is the case that:

$\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}\right]=\mu$

As I understand expectation it is the same as average. In this whole comparison we are interested in the deviation between the average, and an expectation given $n$ r.v's as I understand it. I am however unsure of why it then is the case that $X_1 = \mu$, and what the expression $E[X_1] = \mu$ actually means. I suspect that  it doesn't mean that you are looking at the average/expectation of just $E[X_1] = \frac{1}{1}*\sum_{n} Pr[X = x_1]$, where $x_1$ is the value corresponding to the variable $X_1$ and $n = 1$ denotes the number of possible values that $X_1$ can take which is to say just a single value.

Furthermore I am not sure why $\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}\right]$ holds.

My second question relates to $\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n^{2}} \operatorname{Var}\left[n \hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n^{2}} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \operatorname{Var}\left[X_{i}\right]=$ $\frac{1}{n} \operatorname{Var}\left[X_{1}\right]$
As I understand it the left hand side of the expression should rather look like:

$\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n} \operatorname{Var}\left[n \hat{\mu}_{n}\right]$

I am not sure is the $n^2$ is related to some rule about expectation in relation to average that I miss and that might also explain my first question.

**EDIT**
I think Galton answered my first question and I do want to accept his answer. However I still have a hard time understanding his comment on the second question which I still struggle with.

Comment: I think the key point you are missing that your $X_i$'s are *identically* distributed. That means moments like expectation and variance to not depend on $i$. We have $E X_1 = E X_2 = \dots = E X_n$, so we can replace every instance of $E X_i$ with $E X_1$. The same is true for variances. The $\hat{\mu}_n$ is the sample average of $X_1,\dots, X_n$, and $E X$ is the expectation. For discrete $X$, this is $\sum_j P(X = x_j) x_j$ but for more general $X$ this is generally an integral.

Comment: But i.i.d doesn't mean that they are uniformly distributed. So I don't see why it holds that $EX_1=EX_2=⋯=EX_n$  If $EX$ is the expectation what is $EX_i$ and $EX_1$ ?Is that the equivalent of picking just a single datapoint, whereas $EX$ is the mean value of all datapoints as described in $\sum_{j} P\left(X=x_{j}\right) x_{j}$?

Comment: Nobody said uniformly distributed. Identically distributed means that the $X_i$ are drawn from the same distribution $F$. Which distribution that is does not matter. So $X_1, \dots, X_n$ have the same distribution $F$. $F$ determines all moments, including expectations. When computing moments, we can then replace $X_i$ in $E X_i$ by a single representative random variable $X$  with distribution $F$, so $E X = E X_1 = \dots =  E X_n$. This is not the same a picking a single data point. It is a single random variable that has the same properties as all the $X_1,\dots, X_n$.

Comment: Ok, I think I start to undersatnd. And the $\mu_n$ in the lefthand side of 
 the expression, is just another representative with same properties as $X_1$  why we get $\mathbb{E}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_{1}\right]=\mu$?
$\\$


But what about my second question then? I am still not sure why the above can explain that to be the case?

Comment: We have $E \hat{\mu}_n = E n^{-1}\sum_{I=1}^n X_i = n^{-1}\sum_{I=1}^n E X_i =   n^{-1}\sum_{I=1}^n E X_1 = E X_1$. The second equality is because the expectations of a sum is the sum of the expectations. If you understand why that is the case, you should be able to figure out why independence (or lack of correlation) implies $\mathrm{Var}(\hat{\mu}_n) = \mathrm{Var}(X_1)/n$.

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand or agree. The first part you write about linearity of expectation (I guess?) I can agree with. But I still have a hard time figuring out why $\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n^{2}} \operatorname{Var}\left[n \hat{\mu}_{n}\right]$ would be effected byt that in such that we get $n^{-2}$ If you were to take n out of the parenthesis of the right hand side due to theroem B.26 you would be left with $n^{-1}$ and therefore $\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n} \operatorname{Var}\left[ \hat{\mu}_{n}\right]$ wouldnd hold.

Comment: Now I think I understand. So to answer first part of my second question $\operatorname{Var}\left[\hat{\mu}_{n}\right]=\frac{1}{n^{2}} \operatorname{Var}\left[n \hat{\mu}_{n}\right]$ I think you use that $Var(cX) = c^2 Var(X)$ WHy it is the case that you reach the second statement I am not sure of. And the latter expression $n^{-1} \sum_{I=1}^{n} E X_{1}= E X_{1}$ because of the independence, why the $n*EX_1$ cancels out with $n^{-1}$.

Comment: If you're going to self-answer, please include all the details in the answer rather than just referencing the comments. Comments are not durable on SE so future users may not benefit unless the answer transcribes them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key point I was missing was that your $X_{i}$ 's are identically distributed. That means moments like expectation and variance to not depend on $i$. We have $E X_{1}=E X_{2}=\cdots=E X_{n}$, so we can replace every instance of $E X_{i}$ with $E X_{1}$. The same is true for variances. The $\hat{\mu}_{n}$ is the sample average of $X_{1}, \ldots, X_{n}$, and $E X$ is the expectation. For discrete $X$, this is $\sum_{j} P\left(X=x_{j}\right) x_{j}$ but for more general $X$ this is generally an integral.